# Как сослаться на объект из одного скрипта в другом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт Tile в котором находится метод *ExplodeExternal()* и есть ещё один скрипт Grid в котором хранится List *minedTiles*. Как обратиться к членам *minedTiles* из скрипта Tile и вызвать к каждому из них метод *ExplodeExternal*? Компилятор при запуске жалуется на *NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Все лишнее удалено. Собственно проблема в методе Explode(), но как исправить не знаю. Необходимо сослаться на каждого члена списка minedTiles(), но что-то не работает.

Сами скрипты:
Grid

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject TilePrefab; // Переменная для Префаба клетки

    public List<GameObject> minedTiles;

    public void CreateTiles()
    {
        allTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        float coordinateX = 0.0f;
        float coordinateY = 0.0f;
        int tilesCreated = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
            {
                GameObject newTile = Instantiate(TilePrefab, new Vector2(transform.position.x + coordinateX, transform.position.y + coordinateY), transform.rotation);
                coordinateX += distanceBetweenTiles;
                allTiles.Add(newTile);
                newTile.GetComponentInChildren<Tile>().ID = tilesCreated;
                tilesCreated++;
            }
            coordinateX = 0.0f;
            coordinateY += distanceBetweenTiles;
        }

        AssignedMines();
    }

    public void AssignedMines()
    {
        dontMinedTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        minedTiles = new List<GameObject>();
        dontMinedTiles.AddRange(allTiles);

        for (int assignedMines = 0; assignedMines < numberOfMines; assignedMines++)
        {
            GameObject currentTile = dontMinedTiles[Random.Range(0, dontMinedTiles.Count)];

            minedTiles.Add(currentTile);
            dontMinedTiles.Remove(currentTile);
            currentTile.GetComponentInChildren<Tile>().isMined = true;
        }

    }
```

и Tile

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool isMined = false;
    public TextMesh counter;

    public Color32 zeroColor;
    public GameObject zeroTile;
    public GameObject bomb;
    public GameObject selector;

    public List<GameObject> adjacentTiles;
    public int adjacentMines;

    void UncoverTile()
    {
        if (!isMined)
        {
            state = "uncovered";
            counter.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
            zeroTile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = zeroColor;

            if (adjacentMines == 0)
                UncoveredAdjacentTiles();
        }
        else
            Explode();
    }

    void Explode()
    {
        state = "detonated";
        GetComponent<Tile>().bomb.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<Tile>().counter.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < GetComponent<Grid>().minedTiles.Count; i++)
        {
            var temp = GetComponent<Grid>().minedTiles[i].GetComponent<Tile>();
            temp.ExplodeExternal();
        }

    }

    public void ExplodeExternal()
    {
        state = "detonated";
        GetComponent<Tile>().bomb.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, вопрос решен, если у кого-то возникнет такая проблема, то решение заключалось в том, что список надо было сделать статичным, и после этого обращаться к нему не через GetComponent, а напрямую по названию класса, т.е Grid.minedTiles[i].GetComponent.ExplodeExternal();

Comment: Статические переменные - это, по сути, глобальные переменные, что очень плохо и такая "привычка" решения рано или поздно вам всю игру сломает.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker возможно, пока что иного решения я не придумал.